# How to generate a query that retrieves the count of test cases in a test cycle?

Tags: curl, automation, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

We have number of test cycles which contain many test cases each.I need to get the exact count of test cases in a particular test cycle . i have the following query :

```
curl -v -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET ALL 'https://jira.domain.com:port/rest/api/2/search?zql=project = "ABC" AND fixVersion = "6.5" AND cycleName in ("SPCC-P1.4.2")'
```

The result of the above query in json gives a field "total" but it displays the number of times the test cycle were executed. i need the number of test cases in the test cycle.
Any help appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the count of test cases in the test cycle, you might have to use the zapi for jira add-on . Test Cases or Executions as they are called in Jira cannot be retrieved from the query you mentioned as far as i know.
Please refer : [ZAPI DOC](http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#reference/executionresource/get-execution-information/get-execution-information)

- /rest/api/2/project : will give the project Id of the projects.
- /rest/api/2/project/"projId"/versions : will fetch you version id's
- /rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId="projId" : will fetch the test 
  cycles with their id's.

Finally 
/rest/.../latest/cycle?projectId="id"&versionId="id"&cycleId="id" : should fetch you a field "totalExecutions" which is the total number of test cases in that cycle.